# Haskell RealFrac error

Tags: haskell

The error : Instance of RealFrac Int required for definition of dayshoursmins

I understand that this error is because I'm changing the type - or something along those lines - and that it doesnt match (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b. I'm just not sure how to fix it. The error occurs on line 2. I have tried using fromIntegral however I may be using it incorrectly.

```
dayshoursmins :: Int -> (Int, Int, Int)
dayshoursmins x = (days, hours, minutes)
where
    days = floor (x / (24 * 60))
    a = x - (days * (24 * 60))
    hours = floor (a / 60)
    b = a - (hours * 60)
    minutes = b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/` function if for fractional numbers and returning `Fractional`:

```
> :t (/)
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

If you want to use integer division, use the `div` function instead:

```
dayshoursmins :: Int -> (Int, Int, Int)
dayshoursmins x = (days, hours, minutes)
    where
        days = x `div` (24 * 60)
        a = x - (days * (24 * 60))
        hours =  a `div` 60
        b = a - (hours * 60)
        minutes = b
```

Comment: and by integer division do you mean the `div` acts as the floor function aswell

Comment: Yes. This is the reason I removed `floor` as well.